# ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios

> ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key
>   CFBundleShortVersionString 'bf86d1735303e35c0d1159ce97d252246f972aa7'
>   in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most
>   three non-negative integers."

Answer (score 1):

This error is most likely due to entering letters, punctuations or non-English characters in the entry called "Bundle version string (short) in the project information tab of Xcode. As the message suggests, you should use values like 1.0 or 1.0.1 .

Comment: I have modified. It still doesn't work. I can not found the value 'bf86d1735303e35c0d1159ce97d252246f972aa7' in the project.

Comment: Please try searching for "CFBundleShortVersionString" in the project instead. Or open the Info.plist file as a text file, and look for the text.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. This wil be a great help for debugging, since many won't think of having the problem there.